# EF Combine several tables into one IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

I'm using OData (WebAPI and EF) to query a database. And now I have to "*merge*" three tables into one result.

I have 3 tables and an interface, which looks like this:

```
public class Authority : IAssociationEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AuthorityId { get; set; }
}

public class Company : IAssociationEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}

public class Organization : IAssociationEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
}

public interface IAssociationEntity
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there are some obvious similarities between the three tables, but for some reasons they need to stay in separate tables. What I need is to use paging and search all three by name, and present them in the same list for a user.

I'm looking for something that would look like this in SQL

```
SELECT TOP 4 a.* FROM
(
    SELECT CompanyID, Name from Company WHERE Name = 'Bob'
    UNION
    SELECT OrganizationID, Name from Organization WHERE Name = 'Bob'
    UNION
    SELECT AuthorityID, Name from Authority WHERE Name = 'Bob'
) AS a
```

Is there a way to merge three tables into one `IQueryable`?

I would like to merge these three tables into an `IQueryable<IAssociationEntity>`. I really do need to use the interface (or possibly a base class) and to get the results as an `IQueryable` for my OData implementation. Something like this, but it doesn't compile:

```
var query = db.Companies
    .Concat(db.Organizations)
    .Concat(db.Authorities);
IQueryable<IAssociationEntity> mergedTables = query.Cast<IAssociationEntity>();

// Here is an EXAMPLE usage.
// What I really need is to return the IQueryable<IAssociationEntity> for my OData.
var result = mergedTables.Where(x => x.Name == "Bob").OrderBy(x => x.Name).Skip(2).Take(10);
```

And my usage for the odata controller:

```
public class AssociationController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public override IQueryable<IAssociationEntity> Get(ODataQueryOptions<IAssociationEntity> q)
    {
        // return my IQueryable here...
    }
}
```

Needless to say, I do not want to read the entire table into memory when creating the `IQueryable`. I actually do need to use paging since several of these three tables have millions of rows.

**FINAL SOLUTION ENDED UP AS:**

```
  var query = db.Companies.Select(x => new AssociationEntity { Name = x.Name })
.Concat(db.Organizations.Select(x => new AssociationEntity { Name = x.Name }))
.Concat(db.Authorities.Select(x => new AssociationEntity { Name = x.Name }));
    return query;
```

And when executing against the queryable:

```
_query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("M")).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Skip(10).Take(50).ToList();
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll2].[Name] AS [C2]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Name] LIKE N'%M%'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Organization] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent2].[Name] LIKE N'%M%'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        1 AS [C1], 
        [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Authority] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE [Extent3].[Name] LIKE N'%M%') AS [UnionAll2]
    ORDER BY [UnionAll2].[Name] ASC
    OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to query all three separately, then merge the results. Paging, ordering etc, how would that be done across several tables anyway?

Comment: can you tell me why this difference : `WHERE Name LIKE '%Bob%'` on one place, other place you have used  `Where(x => x.Name == "Bob")` Why ?

Comment: @Sampath - Good catch! It was more of an example of a possible SQL output, and not what I'm really after. I've updated the question.

Comment: OK,can we have a feedback for http://stackoverflow.com/a/39696353/1077309 then ?

Comment: @Sampath, Yes. Patience my friend. I'm trying it out.

Comment: Aha..OK Sure :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `Class` instead of `Interface` `IAssociationEntity`.I named it as `AssociationEntity`.

I have converted your original **TSQL query** this :

```
SELECT TOP 4 a.* FROM
(
    SELECT CompanyID, Name from Company WHERE Name = 'Bob'
    UNION
    SELECT OrganizationID, Name from Organization WHERE Name = 'Bob'
    UNION
    SELECT AuthorityID, Name from Authority WHERE Name = 'Bob'
) AS a
```

To **Linq To Entity Query** as shown below.

```
var queryKey ="Bob";

var query = ((from c in db.Company  where (c.Name = queryKey) select new AssociationEntity { Name = c.Name }).Take(4))
.Concat((from o in db.Organization  where (o.Name = queryKey) select new AssociationEntity { Name = o.Name }).Take(4))
.Concat((from a in db.Authority  where (a.Name = queryKey) select new AssociationEntity { Name = a.Name }).Take(4));
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just do as follows:

```
var result = db.Companies.Where(x => x.Name == "Bob").Select(x => new { x.Name })
             .Concat(db.Organizations.Where(y => y.Name == "Bob").Select(y => new { y.Name }))
             .Concat(db.Authorities.Where(z => z.Name == "Bob").Select(z => new { z.Name })
             .OrderBy(x => x.Name).Skip(2).Take(10);
```

You can replace the Anonymous object inside the `Select` method with a base class.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var query = db.Companies.Select(x => new { Id = x.CompanyId, x.Name })
            .Concat(db.Organizations.Select(x => new { Id = x.OrganizationId, x.Name }))
            .Concat(db.Authorities.Select(x => new { Id = x.AuthorityId, x.Name }));

var result = query.Where(x => x.Name == "Bob").OrderBy(x => x.Name).Skip(2).Take(10);
```

The generated SQL is:

```
SELECT
    [UnionAll2].[CompanyId] AS [C1],
    [UnionAll2].[CompanyId1] AS [C2],
    [UnionAll2].[Name] AS [C3]
    FROM  (SELECT
        [Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId],
        [Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId1],
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Companies] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE N'Bob' = [Extent1].[Name]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT
        [Extent2].[OrganizationId] AS [OrganizationId],
        [Extent2].[OrganizationId] AS [OrganizationId1],
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Organizations] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE N'Bob' = [Extent2].[Name]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT
        [Extent3].[AuthorityId] AS [AuthorityId],
        [Extent3].[AuthorityId] AS [AuthorityId1],
        [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name]
        FROM [dbo].[Authorities] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE N'Bob' = [Extent3].[Name]) AS [UnionAll2]
    ORDER BY [UnionAll2].[Name] ASC
    OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very similiar to the others, but I needed to return my query as an IQueryable, and then I cannot work with anonymous types.